# marshal dump format error(0xa)

Tags: ruby, marshalling

My hash:

```
$settings =
{
  :first_run=>true, :version=>1.01, :game_variables=>{}, :game_switches=>{9=>false}
}
```

Save Code:

```
marshal_dump = Marshal.dump($settings)
file = File.new(file_path, 'w')
file.write marshal_dump
file.close
```

Load code:

```
$settings = Marshal.load(File.binread(file_path))
```

So far everything still works. But as soon as I add another variable to the $settings hash and save it and then attempt to load it:

```
$settings[:test] = 'woohoo!'
save() # saves the hash to disk
load() # loads the hash from disk
```

It will raise the error:

```
Argument error occured. dump format error(0xa)
```

**Solution:**
(thanks goes to ilan berci)

```
def dump_settings
    File.open(FILENAME,'w') do|file|
      Marshal.dump($settings, file)
    end
  end

  def load_settings
    $settings = if File.exists?(FILENAME)
      File.open(FILENAME) do|file|
        Marshal.load(file)
      end
      else
        create # custom function that fills the $settings for first use
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reading the file in binary mode but the contents haven't been dumped like that.

use:

$settings = Marshal.load(File.open(file_path))

Comment: I'm sorry. This was indeed the problem. I had 2 save functions and I forgot to replace the code in the other one too.